# How do i read a folder and display the contents in java.

Tags: java, directory

I'm creating a videogame (textbased) in java, and i need to read a folder to display several .java file names as the savegames. how do i do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class, and its methods [`list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) or [`listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

```
String folderPath = ...;
for(String fileName : new File(folderPath).list())
{
    if(fileName.endsWith(".java") && fileName.contains("savegames"))
    {
         System.out.println(fileName);
    }
}
```

Also you can use the same methods with a [`FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html), which are [`list(FilenameFilter filter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) or [`listFiles(FilenameFilter filter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29):

```
String folderPath = "";
FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter()
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return name.endsWith(".java") && name.contains("savegames");
    }
};

for(String fileName : new File(folderPath).list(filter))
{
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Although, I don't know if I would include "fileName.endsWith(".java")". I would create my save files with my own extension. +1 you beat me to it.